# Вопрос по Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Сколько бы не читал документации, всегда говорят, вот Hibernate за вас делает это, делает то, автоматически меняет названия таблицы, когда это нужно, при указании в аннотации @Column (name = "name") делает столбец name, но вот вопрос: Hibernate может делать что-либо только с заранее созданной таблицей? То есть каждую таблицу, которая у нас есть, мы должны описывать entity-классом, причем в точности? Или же Hibernate должен их (таблицы) сам создавать (основываясь на entity)?

Comment: Всё зависит от настроек. Он может и так и эдак. Однако правильнее будет, всё же, создавать отдельно таблицы, а потом уже по ним создавать `Entity`. Ибо, если делать наоборот что-то может пойти не так. Например тип к-л колонки будет неподходящим или неоптимальным. Ну и больше контроля над процессом получите.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а что будет, если у меня допустим в Entity классе есть поле String, а в БД это поле типа VARCHAR(10). Будет ли выдавать ошибку при попытке вставить туда значение больше 10 символов?

Comment: Да, должно будет выкинуть ошибку с соответствующим сообщением.